# How big can a string be in a Django field if the database is Postgresql and db_index=True?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design, indexing

I'm working on a Django website that has a PostgreSQL database, and one of my model's has a 'description' field that I'd like to give an index. Is there a maximum string size that can be added to this column?

[Django's documentation on PostgreSQL indices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#indexes-for-varchar-and-text-columns) makes it seem like there is no limit, since you can create indices for TextFields that don't define a max_lenth. However, I found [this post about btree column size errors](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/index-row-size-exceeds-btree-maximum-2713-Solutions-td1846396.html), which makes me think that 2713 / 4 - 4 = 674.25 is the most UTF-8 characters that would always fit. Can anyone point me to documentation for this or share there experiences with trying to put indices on Django TextFields?

Comment: That's a post from 2005, mind. What PostgreSQL version are you using? AFAIK on modern PostgreSQL there is a limit, but it's 1/2 a page (4kb, since Pg has 8k pages).

Comment: I'm using version 9.3, so this seems like the answer I was looking for. Thanks also for the followup about text compression.

Comment: There's usually not much point in b-tree indexing big text fields anyway, given that all a b-tree can do is test for equality, less than, or greater than. A `text_pattern_ops` b-tree is marginally more useful as it supports prefix search (`LIKE 'blah%'`), but again, not the usual thing you do with big text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a limit, but it's not tiny.

> ERROR:  index row requires 9400 bytes, maximum size is 8191

To trigger this:

```
CREATE TABLE bigtext(x text);

CREATE INDEX bigtext_x ON bigtext(x);

 INSERT INTO bigtext(x) SELECT repeat('x', 819200);
```

Given the error you'd expect this to fail:

```
INSERT INTO bigtext(x) SELECT repeat('x', 8192);
```

but because of compression, it won't; you can tack an extra zero on and it'll still fit.

Smaller, less repetitive and therefore less compressible texts will fit less before overrunning a page and failing. In theory if you had totally random garbage then only 8191 bytes should fit, but in reality it'll still be a bit more on a utf-8 db because utf-8 doesn't permit total randomness; probably in the vicinity of 8191 totally random utf-8 *chars* though.

For this reason you can't have a simple `CHECK` constraint, it's not as simple as "number of chars".

You might find `pg_column_size(...)` useful; it tells you the on-disk compressed size of a datum. It won't help you in a `CHECK` constraint though, because it always shows unTOASTed datums at full uncompressed size.

The PostgreSQL docs could describe this limit a lot better (or at all).

For bigger fields you can index the `left` n bytes, or use a tool like `tsearch2` to do fulltext search instead.